create a model to predict the correct outcome for each record in the vendor data. whether to link it to an existing company or to create a new
Built an intelligent model capable of predicting the correct outcome for each record in the vendor dataset—whether to link it to an existing company or to create a new entry. Additionally, for records that match an existing company, your model should recommend the appropriate companyID.

train_set_records.csv: Contains the records along with the attributes of the vendor dataset for training data
train_set_labels.csv: Contains the task outcome ('Add New' or 'Add Exist') and the appropriate company ID in case a link is present. For Add New cases, linkedCompany will be None
test_set_records.csv: Contains the records along with the attributes of the vendor dataset for evaluating the model
searchResults.parquet: Each vendor record has some relevant companies retrieved from the CIQ universe. The outcome of the task shall be based on the relevant companies shared within the relevant set of companies

Note: Every vendor record could only have 2 possible outcomes as mentioned above. If the outcome predicted is Add Exist, the actual link will be made to a single companyID.
For definitions of the vendor attribute, please make use of the assigned business representative
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import numpy as np

# Load datasets
train_records = pd.read_csv('Data/train_set_records.csv')
train_labels = pd.read_csv('Data/train_set_labels.csv')
test_records = pd.read_csv('Data/test_set_records.csv')
search_results = pd.read_parquet('Data/searchResults.parquet')

# Merge train records with labels
train_data = train_records.merge(train_labels, on='DUNS_NUMBER')

# Feature Engineering (example: encoding categorical variables)
label_encoders = {}
for column in train_data.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns:
    le = LabelEncoder()
    train_data[column] = le.fit_transform(train_data[column].astype(str))
    label_encoders[column] = le

# Split features and target
X = train_data.drop(['y_hat', 'linkedCompany'], axis=1)  # features
y = train_data['y_hat']  # target

# Train-test split
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Model Training
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Validation
y_val_pred = model.predict(X_val)
print(classification_report(y_val, y_val_pred))

# Prepare test data
test_data = test_records.copy()
for column in test_data.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns:
    test_data[column] = label_encoders[column].transform(test_data[column].astype(str))

# Make predictions
test_predictions = model.predict(test_data)

# Create submission DataFrame
submission = pd.DataFrame({
    'DUNS_NUMBER': test_records['DUNS_NUMBER'],
    'y_hat': [None if pred == 'Add New' else search_results.loc[search_results['DUNS_NUMBER'] == duns, 'companyID'].tolist() for duns, pred in zip(test_records['DUNS_NUMBER'], test_predictions)]
})

# Fill None values for 'Add New' cases
submission['y_hat'] = submission['y_hat'].apply(lambda x: [None]*3 if x is None else x)

# Save to CSV
submission.to_csv('final_submission.csv', index=False)


our output should be in this format :
 DUNS_NUMBER    y_hat
0   123456788   [None, None, None]
1   546656567   [637022184, None, None]
2   567656667   [None, None, None]
3   676878344   [36575686345, 543657546436, 5343564363, 678143566, 243565356, 5436635235]
4   3546655778  [1232335463, None, None]

![Instead of linked comp id I am getting True false. seems like encoding problem. Do we need to use it.][please let me know if any other suggestion for using any other model to do my task.]
